# Getting user input for string array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have several methods I will be using in this program. I'm just wanting a little help with one part. I have to make a program that prompts a user to enter the number of elements to be sorted. Once that number is entered, it will prompt the user again to enter the elements themselves. They must be strings. I wrote some quick code to see how this is going to work, but I used ints instead of strings. I can't figure out how to get the program to take a string rather than an int. 
It would look like this on the console: 
Enter number of elements: 4

```
Element 1: Apple
Element 2: Banana
Element 3: Orange
Element 4: Kiwi
```

Then it would sort them in ascending order. I haven't reached the sorting part yet, so it's irrelevant right now. I'm just wanting to know how in the world I can loop my Element 1:, Element 2:, etc with a String as input.

> Note: I cannot use the Arrays class, which makes this more difficult for me.

Here's what I have using ints:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sort_as_Inserted {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter number of elements to be sorted: ");

       int num_of_elements = input.nextInt();

       int[] num = new int[num_of_elements];

       for (int i = 0; i < num_of_elements; i++)
       {
           System.out.print("Element" + (i + 1) + ": ");

           num[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }//end Main
}//end Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of input.nextInt() you can just put input.next() and that will get the next immediate string value entered.  You can also do input.nextLine() if I remember right and that will give you an entire line as a string value which can be useful for when reading in a large text file since you will be able to tackle it line by line while reading it in.

EDIT:

This is a little tricky without using an array.  You can put them into a large string value.  Appending a String Builder object would be better since it is mutable but that is probably not in your current scope.

```
String elements ="";
for(int i = 0; i <= num_of_elements; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter an element");
    elements += input.next() + " ";
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to create a loop to prompt the elements to be entered (Element 1, Element 2, etc.). That's where the initial int array comes from. It is the number of string elements the user will be entering. Also, I used input.nextInt() just to see how the program would work by entering numbers instead of strings.

Comment: So your user enters the number of times to loop right?  So just create a for loop to iterate the number of times they enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example to see the outcome. Puting the below code in a loop can solve the problem. Within your loop you can add each input to a Collection. (You do not need to have `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)` in the loop)

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter element: ");
el = in.nextLine(); // reads string
```

To sort you can look into HashSet and [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) from the documentation

EDIT:
Maybe something like this would do.

```
TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String element = “”;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    element =in.nextLine();
    ts.add(element);
}
```

Comment: I can create an array, I just can't use the Arrays class or Collections Class, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Basically, I need to keep the initial int array to loop the number of times the user chooses. Then I need to have Strings as user input along with that loop. Upon the first prompt, they will enter a word, then another word, and another until it reaches the end of their first number. Each element will be a string, and I have to go about this the long way.

Answer (score 0):

To get the input as a `String` you need to use:

```
String num_of_elements = input.nextLine();
```

Once you have that, you can convert it to an `int` by using:

```
Integer.parseInt(num_of_elements);
```

Your code might look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter number of elements to be sorted: ");

       String num_of_elements = input.nextLine();

       String[] num = new String[Integer.parseInt(num_of_elements)];

       for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(num_of_elements); i++)
       {
           System.out.print("Input Element" + (i + 1) + ": ");
           num[i] = input.nextLine();
        }

       int index = 0;
        for(String element : num){
            System.out.println("Element at index " + index + " = " + element);
       }

        input.close(); 
    }//end Main
```

Comment: Those last two comments really make sense. I was thinking of the add/assign, as well as parsing. I'm gonna write some scratch code, try a few things and see what I come up with. Thank you guys for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

```
As per my understanding, you are trying to read a number of string input values, but do not want to use an Array.

please find the below program, where I am using a list interface and any of its implementation classes (could be arraylist, linkedlist etc.)

this program will store the input values and then collections class will sort it for you. One more important thing, you should always close the scanner.

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of elements to be sorted: ");

        int num_of_elements = input.nextInt();
        List elementList = new LinkedList();
        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_elements; i++) {
            System.out.print("Element" + (i + 1) + ": ");
            elementList.add(input.next());
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println(elementList);
        Collections.sort(elementList);
        System.out.println(elementList);
    }
}
```